# Youtube-dl: Decrypt and/or play MP4 - PlayReady/DRM/cenc/dash

Tags: youtube-dl, drm, dash

A Video-file is downloaded with youtube-dl based on mpd-file. However ffmpeg post-processor fails to convert it to playable mp4. The file downloaded with youtube-dl is encrypted. Is there a possibility to decrypt the mp4-file with the information in the mpd-manifest? Or are there other solutions to download and play PlayReady-protected-content?

[Link of manifest.mpd](https://jsonformatter.org/xml-viewer/17c29d)

Answer (score 3):

The short answer: no, there is really no way to decrypt the content and save it on your disk as plaintext. That, I'm afraid, is the whole point of DRM.

The longer answer: in principle it is possible to play back the still-protected-but-offline content, if you manage to acquire the DRM license *and* if that DRM license contains sufficient playback rights (i.e. it's not expired nor it has other restrictions). But then you are forced to play it back with the same "agent" (loosely, the same application) that acquired the license -- for example, Edge or Internet Explorer or Windows 10's Movies & TV app (since the stream seems to be encrypted with Microsoft PlayReady).

All in all, not for the faint of heart, but theoretically possible.

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer(many people answer on this question like I am a criminal...) Next step; I would like to play such a DRM-protected stream from a popular TV-station here on this site: http://stream-tester.jwplayer.com/ just as I am curious if it should work. 
The only thing I can't find, is the DRM-license-server. Do you know how to extract or find that URL so I can play the ondemand-content of the televisionstation on the testsite of jwplayer? Or is this also not possible?

Comment: Usually the license acquisition URL is "hidden" in the manifest you linked above, in the `<mspr:pro>` tag or in the `<cenc:pssh>` one or even in the "init segment" (in this case, https://dcs-jite-df9y0sk8rfj8p7d7.gcdn.anvato.net/prod/ABEDF2D7E651454A826B9FDF18C5B552/4200000/fmp4-cenc-init-video.mp4).
However, in this case it is not. That means the license acquisition URL is provided by the web player application as part of its JavaScript code, and not in the manifest.